# How to store integer in fewest bits possible in Java

Tags: java, byte, bit

I have numbers lower than 16 and I want to store them the smallest way possible. I currently convert my integer to a byte but I don't need the whole byte. I think I only need 4 bits to hold my number. 
I want to use as little of a byte as I can.

```
byte solutionLength = (byte) myArray.length;
return solutionLength;
```

`myArray.length` is always less than 12. 
How can I use as few bits to store to my variable `solutionLength` ?

Comment: Off topic: Any reason you need to worry about memory so much? Just curious

Comment: Because I store about 800 million of the returned value in an array. @ZeldaZach

Comment: [`BitSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html)

Comment: @ProgrammingCuber Maybe you should look into alternative methods as I'd never store _that_ many results in an array... can you possibly shed some light as to why you're doing this exactly?

Comment: this array contains solutions lengths of branches in a search algorithm which searches 1.5 billion nodes total. Currently only need 800 million of the 1.5 billion. @ZeldaZach

Comment: [`BitSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html)

Comment: BitSet helps if you want to store 1-bit values; it doesn't help for 4-bit or n-bit values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's impossible to have data types lower than a byte in size. If you have multiple numbers to store you can do a trick: store two 4-bit values in one byte.

```
byte storage = (byte) (((byte)myArray.length << 4) | (byte)myArray2.length);
```

Here you store two numbers in one byte.
To access them try:

```
byte myArrayLength = (byte) ((storage & 0xf0) >> 4);
byte myArrayLength2 = (byte) (storage & 0x0f);
```

But integer would be better solution for it by avoiding type conversions

Answer (score 3):

You can use byte array, each byte will hold two values - one in higher 4 bits and another in lower for bits. E.g. 0x1F holds 1 and F. And you need to create a class which will calculate values by index.